# I want to use SQL to Populate the Primary Key Value

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-insert, uniqueidentifier, identifier

I want to use SQL statements on insert to insert the new / next identifier  value for my Primary Unique Index while being able to support joins with PK and FK relationships> What is the simplest solution?  Data type/length recommendation?   The data is reference, operational and technical metadata relatively lower volumes to transactional data.

Comment: Do you mean Primary key by "primary unique index" ?

Comment: Nobody can provide an answer here because there isn't a question. Simplest is not something you should every worry about, the ease of the developer is not important. It is about a solid data model that will allow for performant queries. The datatype would depend on what the key is.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Agree I degressed and went to the dark side

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your data needs, I would use an INT for the primary key as you state this is relatively lower volumes of transactional data. INT supports -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. As I would use an auto incrementing integer beginning at 1 as the primary key, if you plan to have more than 2 billion rows then use a big int which supports up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. This will automatically populate your primary key.

Comment: Thank You. I decided to go with an int identity vs a guid or some other value. I also realized my insert into did not need to declare the identity field